# JW player works on android via web but apk not working

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, jwplayer

I am using JW-Player to play an embedded YouTube video. I am having some issues playing the video. I have uploaded my files to my webspace and the videos work when clicked on, but when i compile an apk (using phonegap build), and install the apk on my phone (samsung galaxy 2 and htc desire), i click on the video and it shows a black screen.

Heres my code to play the video:

```
<div id='mediaspace2'><b>Player is Loading...</b></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
jwplayer("mediaspace2").setup({
    file: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VFrnWAK-DLk",
    height: 300,
    width: 270,
    modes: [
        { type: "html5" },
        { type: "flash", src: "/jwplayer/player.swf" },
        { type: "download" }
    ]

});
```

I dont understand how I can visit my website via android phone and the videos play but when I create an APK the videos will not play through the program. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

*Forgot to add im using version 5.9 of JW player, and upto date flash players.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Problem might be with `{ type: "flash", src: "/jwplayer/player.swf" }`
make sure to link your swf,js and other stuff correctly when using PhoneGap because for sure the link to such items wont be same as it was on the web.